# retornar dados de um select no modal

Tags: jquery, modal

Faço `insert`, `update` e `select` com o modal. Quando faço editar carrega os dados retornados nos `inputs`, na `checkbox`, nos `textarea`, mas nos `select` não carrega a informação.

Código onde consulto os dados e crio o botão `editar`:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);  
$output;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
 {  
   $output .= '

         <form id="insert_form">
             <div class="row clearfix">
                 <div class="col_half1">
                     <label>Código Utente</label>
                        <div class="input_field"> <span><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-file-code"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" id="codigo1" name="codigo" value="'.$row["codigo"].'" class="form-control" readonly="true"/>
                        </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col_half">
                     <label>Dependência</label>
                        <div class="input_field"> <span><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" id="dependencia2" name="dependencia" value="'.$row["Dependencia"].'" class="form-control" readonly="true"/>
                        </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-footer" >
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button> 
                 <a type="button" name="edit" id="'.$row["Id"].'" data-toggle="modal" href="#add_data_Modal" onclick="inserir_registo()" class="btn btn-primary edit_data">Editar</a>                        
             </div>     
             </form>
             ';  
         }

      $output;
     echo $output;  
    }
```

Para enviar os dados para o `form` do modal para `editar` faço-o desta forma:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function(){  
 var employee_id = $(this).attr("Id");
   $.ajax({  
        url:"./fetchutente",  
        method:"POST",  
        data:{employee_id:employee_id},             
        dataType:"json",  
        success:function(data){
          $('#codigo').val(data.codigo);
          $('#dependencia1').val(data.Dependencia);
          $('#employee_id').val(data.Id);                    
          $('#insert').val("Gravar");  
          $('#add_data_Modal').modal('show');
          }  
      });
    });
```

O `form` do modal que abre para `editar`:

```
<form id="formulario"> 
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col_half1">
          <label>Código Utente</label>
          <div class="input_field"> <span><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-code"></i></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="codigo" name="codigo" placeholder="Código Utente" required="">
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row clearfix">
     <div class="col_half3">
          <label>Dependência</label>
          <div class="input_field"> <span><i aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i></span>
            <select class="form-control" name="dependencia" id="dependencia1" placeholder="Dependência" required="">
               <option></option>
               <?php        
               $sql = "SELECT * FROM raddb.Dependencia ORDER BY Discricao ASC";
               $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
               while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
               echo '<option value="'.$ln['Id'].'">'.$ln['Discricao'].'</option>';
               }
               ?>      
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Mas como mostro na imagem, carrega a informação do `input` com o código, mas o `select` com `name=dependencia`, fica em branco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Também tentei assim, mas também não carrega a informação vinda do `json`:

```
$('select[name="dependencia"]').val(data.Dependencia);
```

Comment: você já deu um `console.log` nesse `data.Dependencia` para ver se está retornando alguma coisa?

Comment: esse `$('select[name="dependencia"]').val();` seta pelo valor do `option` e não pelo conteúdo  texto dentro do `option` html

Comment: @William na consola retorna o valor correto, só não carrega o valor no select

Comment: esse `data.Dependecia` retonar um número ou um texto?

Comment: @William retorna texto

Comment: então ai que está o problema, você tem que setar esse `select` através do `val=""` dos `options` e não pela descrição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao invés de fazer isso:

```
$('select[name="dependencia"]').val(data.Dependencia);
```

Você teria que fazer isso

```
$('select[name="dependencia"]').val(data.DependenciaId);
```

para que ele possa achar o um `option` dentro do seu `select` com o mesmo valor que você quer setar

Comment: quando faço `insert` no `Id é número e quando carrego o form para fazer o `update` retorna texto. Será por causa disso que continua sem carregar a informação?

Comment: @Bruno na verdade o correto seria depois que você fizesse esse `insert` e retornasse esse `id`, você fizesse um `select` para pegar os dados já atualizado, mas poste o seu código que está no `/fetchutente.`  para podermos ver melhor o que você está tentando fazer.

Comment: já resolvi o problema, o problema estava na query que está no `/fetchutente` que retornava no json